# How can I bind to an attached property in a Style.Resource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a prompt text label in the background of a TextBox using attached properties, but I can't resolve the binding to the text caption in a style resource:

Style definition:

```
<Style x:Key="CueBannerTextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="TextBox">
  <Style.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush"
                 AlignmentX="Left"
                 AlignmentY="Center"
                 Stretch="None">
      <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=(EnhancedControls:CueBannerTextBox.Caption), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}"
               Foreground="LightGray"
               Background="White"
               Width="200" />
      </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
  </Style.Resources>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Text"
             Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="{DynamicResource CueBannerBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Text"
             Value="{x:Null}">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="{DynamicResource CueBannerBrush}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Attached property:

```
    public class CueBannerTextBox
{
    public static String GetCaption(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (String)obj.GetValue(CaptionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCaption(DependencyObject obj, String value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Caption", typeof(String), typeof(CueBannerTextBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtProductInterfaceStorageId" 
                 EnhancedControls:CueBannerTextBox.Caption="myCustomCaption"
                 Width="200" 
                 Margin="5" 
                 Style="{StaticResource CueBannerTextBoxStyle}" />
```

The idea is that you can define the text prompt used in the visual brush when you create the textbox, but I'm getting a binding error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBox', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')`

The code works fine if I just hardcode the Label.Content property in the style.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The problem here has to do with the way `Style` works: basically, one "copy" of the `Style` will be created (at first reference), and at that point, there may be multiple `TextBox` controls you want this `Style` applied to - which one will it use for the RelativeSource?</strike>

The (probable) answer is to use a `Template` instead of a `Style` - with a control or data template, you'll be able to access the visual tree of the `TemplatedParent`, and that should get you where you need to be.

EDIT: On further thought, I may be incorrect here...I'll throw together a quick test harness when I'm back in front of a computer and see if I can prove/disprove this.

FURTHER EDIT: While what I originally said was arguably "true", that's not your problem; What Raul said re: the visual tree is correct:

- You are setting the `Background` property on the `TextBox` to a `VisualBrush` instance.
- The `Visual` of that brush is *not* mapped into the Visual Tree of the control.
- As a result, **any** `{RelativeSource FindAncestor}` navigation will fail, as the parent of that visual will be null.
- This is the case regardless of whether it is declared as a `Style` or a `ControlTemplate`.
- All that said, relying on `ElementName` definitely is non-ideal, as it reduces the reusability of the definition.

So, what to do?

I've been wracking my brain overnight trying to think of a way to marshal over the proper inheritance context to the contained brush, with little success...I did come up with this **super-hacky** way, however:

First, the helper property (note: I don't usually style my code this way, but trying to save space):

```
public class HackyMess 
{
    public static String GetCaption(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (String)obj.GetValue(CaptionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCaption(DependencyObject obj, String value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("obj '{0}' setting caption to '{1}'", obj, value);
        obj.SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Caption", typeof(String), typeof(HackyMess),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static object GetContext(DependencyObject obj) { return obj.GetValue(ContextProperty); }
    public static void SetContext(DependencyObject obj, object value) { obj.SetValue(ContextProperty, value); }

    public static void SetBackground(DependencyObject obj, Brush value) { obj.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    public static Brush GetBackground(DependencyObject obj) { return (Brush) obj.GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Context", typeof(object), typeof(HackyMess),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(HackyMess), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.OverridesInheritanceBehavior | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Background", typeof(Brush), typeof(HackyMess),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(default(Brush), OnBackgroundChanged));

    private static void OnBackgroundChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var rawValue = args.NewValue;
        if (rawValue is Brush)
        {
            var brush = rawValue as Brush;
            var previousContext = obj.GetValue(ContextProperty);
            if (previousContext != null && previousContext != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                if (brush is VisualBrush)
                {
                    // If our hosted visual is a framework element, set it's data context to our inherited one
                    var currentVisual = (brush as VisualBrush).GetValue(VisualBrush.VisualProperty);
                    if(currentVisual is FrameworkElement)
                    {
                        (currentVisual as FrameworkElement).SetValue(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, previousContext);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Why can't there be just *one* background property? *sigh*
            if (obj is TextBlock) { obj.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, brush); }
            else if (obj is Control) { obj.SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, brush); }
            else if (obj is Panel) { obj.SetValue(Panel.BackgroundProperty, brush); }
            else if (obj is Border) { obj.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, brush); }
        }
    }
}
```

And now the updated XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="CueBannerTextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="TextBox.Text"
             Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
      <Setter Property="local:HackyMess.Background">
        <Setter.Value>
          <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left"
                       AlignmentY="Center"
                       Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=(local:HackyMess.Caption)}"
                     Foreground="LightGray"
                     Background="White"
                     Width="200" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
          </VisualBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
             Value="True">
      <Setter Property="local:HackyMess.Background"
              Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<TextBox x:Name="txtProductInterfaceStorageId"
         local:HackyMess.Caption="myCustomCaption"
         local:HackyMess.Context="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         Width="200"
         Margin="5"
         Style="{StaticResource CueBannerTextBoxStyle}" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtProductInterfaceStorageId2"
         local:HackyMess.Caption="myCustomCaption2"
         local:HackyMess.Context="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         Width="200"
         Margin="5"
         Style="{StaticResource CueBannerTextBoxStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Label` inside the `VisualBrush` is not a visual child of the `TextBox`, that is the reason why that binding doesn't work. My solution for that problem will be using the `ElementName` binding. But the visual brush you are creating is inside a `Style`'s dictionary resource and then the `ElementName` binding will not work because doesn't find the element id. The solution for that will be to create the `VisualBrush` in a global dictionary resources. See this XAML code for delcaring the `VisualBrush`:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush"
               AlignmentX="Left"
               AlignmentY="Center"
               Stretch="None">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
      <Label Content="{Binding Path=(EnhancedControls:CueBannerTextBox.Caption), ElementName=txtProductInterfaceStorageId}"
             Foreground="#4F48DD"
             Background="#B72121"
             Width="200"
             Height="200" />
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
  </VisualBrush>
  <Style x:Key="CueBannerTextBoxStyle"
         TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Text"
               Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource CueBannerBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Text"
               Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource CueBannerBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
               Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="White" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This code should works. No more code need to be changed so I'm not rewriting all the code.

Hope this solution works for you...

Comment: That looks like it just hardcodes the element name into the style though - how would that be re-usable? I can only have one textbox using this solution?